# Multiple private subnets?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc

We have `dbs`, `basion` ..etc, total 10 things that need to be separated.

If we put each of them into a separated subnet, we have total 10 subnnet and plus 1 for second zone for high availability. So we have total 20 subnets need to be created.

Do we really need to create 20 subnets in total in aws? Because we off-load infrastructure to azamon and amazon uses security group to separate things, I don't find good reason to do that.

I'm considering only two private subnets and two public subnets in two different zone (for ha), adding ec2 instances to a private subnets and use security group to make logical separating between `things`. Two subnets because some aws resource require that, for example: `rds`

Comment: why do you need a subnet for each thing? Classify the subnets to access levels required: public/private/nat'd

Comment: @SathyajithBhat: That's what I'm asking, If on-premises I'd create a subnet for a `thing` that is a `vlan` and route between them, but here we don't know how amazon manage their underlying system. The only way we can separate `thing` is to use `security group`. If I use only one private subnets for all ec2 instances and use `security group` to separate group of ec2 instances, I don't see any benefit to have multiple private subnets for instances here. Is that true?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are correct. You should only need one Public subnet and one Private subnet per Availability Zone.

And, in fact, you could just use public subnets by configuring Security Groups to restrict traffic.

There really is no good reason to put resources in separate subnets unless you have additional security requirements (eg DMZs, subnet sharing, VPC peering).

Answer (score 0):

It is good question, in some situation you want to isolate resources and when you put them to subnets you can use NACL (what improve security).